# Swift - UICollectionView pagination within self sizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I am implementing self sizing `UITableViewCell` containing `UICollectionView` which extends its height based on the number of items received from API.

The views are structured like this

```
UITableView

    UITableViewCell

        UICollectionView

            UICollectionViewCell

            UICollectionViewCell

            UICollectionViewCell
```

When the `UICollectionView` receives new data, `UITableViewCell` frame is updated with the following code

```
layoutIfNeeded()
collectionView.reloadData()
collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()

collectionView.snp.updateConstraints { make in
    make.height.equalTo(collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize).priority(.high)
}
```

The problematic part is adding pagination on scroll to the bottom of the `UICollectionView`. The self sizing code causes that `willDisplay cell` is called for each cell of the `UICollectionView` causing `// Fetch more data` request to trigger, which fetches new data, updates `UICollectionView` height, triggering the API request again, and it's an infinite loop.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if indexPath.item == collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: indexPath.section) - 1 {
        // Fetch more data
    }
}
```

Any idea how to avoid this cycle? Thanks.

Comment: `UICollectionView` is designed to automate scrolling when you have more cells than will fit in the available space. But, it appears you are trying to go the other direction --- resizing your collection view to fit the content, and then putting this *non-scrolling* collection view inside a table view cell (row). Is there a reason you cannot simply use table view cells?

Comment: @DonMag the overall scene layout contains 2 collectionViews - the top one is horizontal scrolling (doesn't need vertical resizing, the height is always predetermined) and the bottom one which has dynamic height and it is expanding as the user scrolls down and fetches more data. The top collectionView is the first row of UITableView and the bottom collectionView is the second row.

Comment: Sounds like the *"bottom collectionView** should be tableView cells, not a collection view embedded in a tableView cell.

Comment: The "bottom collectionView" contains cells that look like UICollectionViewCell, including multiple cells on the same "row", so it needs to be UICollectionView

Comment: Well, as you've seen, trying to counter the design / functionality of a collection view is problematic. Maybe a better approach would be to get rid of the tableView, and instead use a scrollable collectionView, where the first cell would contain your horizontally-scrolling collection view.

Comment: Thanks @DonMag, i was also thinking about replacing the root tableview with collectionview